# In React, what is causing: Encountered two children with the same key, `Color-[object Object]` error when I refresh the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, shopify, refresh

my application works fine until i refresh or re-render the page. There is multiple possible explanations for this, but I cant seem to work it out. The first problem might be in the constructor, as I am not sure if I'm allowed to do it this way. However I need to use the match.params to get the right product to use on the page.
The error:

```
index.js:1 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `Size-[object Object]`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.
at select
at VariantSelector (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:7811:1)
at div
at ProductPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:6069:5)
at C (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77932:37)
at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:74833:75)
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77675:29)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77877:29)
at div
at CollectionPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:9200:3)
at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:74833:75)
at Spinner (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:7939:5)
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77675:29)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77877:29)
at div
at ShopPage (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:10106:1)
at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:74833:75)
at Route (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77675:29)
at Switch (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77877:29)
at div
at App (http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:803:5)
at ConnectFunction (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:74833:75)
at Elements (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:38972:30)
at PersistGate (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:83105:5)
at Router (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:77310:30)
at BrowserRouter (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:76930:35)
at Provider (http://localhost:3000/static/js/0.chunk.js:74546:20)
```

And on the front-end:
Before refresh:

[image]

After refresh:

[image]

The error when I try to select an option after the refresh:

[image]

The code of the product page:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import { createStructuredSelector } from 'reselect';

import CustomButton from '../custom-button/custom-button.component';

import './product-detail.styles.scss';

import {addCollectionId} from '../../redux/cart/cart.utils';

import VariantSelector from '../variant-selector/VariantSelector';

import { selectCheckout, selectCart } from '../../redux/cart/cart.selectors';

import { client } from '../../shopify/shopify.utils';

// constants
const ONE_SIZE_FITS_MOST = "One Size Fits Most";

class ProductPage extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    const { match, collection} = this.props;
    const { productId } = match.params;
    const product = collection.products.find((product) => (product.title.toLowerCase() === productId.toLowerCase()));
    let defaultOptionValues = {};
    product.options.forEach((selector) => {
      defaultOptionValues[selector.name] = selector.values[0].value;
    });

    this.state = { 
      selectedOptions: defaultOptionValues,
      product: product, 
    };

    this.handleOptionChange = this.handleOptionChange.bind(this);
    this.handleQuantityChange = this.handleQuantityChange.bind(this);
    this.findImage = this.findImage.bind(this);
  }

  findImage(images, variantId) {
    const primary = images[0];

    const image = images.filter(function (image) {
      return image.variant_ids.includes(variantId);
    })[0];

    return (image || primary).src;
  }

  handleOptionChange(event) {
    const target = event.target
    let selectedOptions = this.state.selectedOptions;
    selectedOptions[target.name] = target.value;
    //console.log('selectedVariant', selectedOptions);
    const selectedVariant = client.product.helpers.variantForOptions(this.state.product, selectedOptions)
    //console.log(selectedVariant);
    this.setState({
      selectedVariant: selectedVariant,
      selectedVariantImage: selectedVariant.attrs.image
    });
    console.log(this.state)
  }

  handleQuantityChange(event) {
    this.setState({
      selectedVariantQuantity: event.target.value
    });
  }

  addVariantToCart(variantId, quantity) {
    const lineItemsToAdd = [{variantId, quantity: parseInt(quantity, 10)}]
    const checkoutId = this.props.checkout.id
    client.checkout.addLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToAdd).then(res => {
      this.props.dispatch({type: 'ADD_VARIANT_TO_CART', payload: {isCartOpen: true, checkout: res}});
    });
  }

  render() {
    let aOptionNames = [];
    let variantImage = this.state.selectedVariantImage || this.state.product.images[0]
    let variant = this.state.selectedVariant || this.state.product.variants[0]
    let variantQuantity = this.state.selectedVariantQuantity || 1
    let variantSelectors = this.state.product.options.map((option) => {
      aOptionNames.push(option.name);
      return (
        <VariantSelector
          handleOptionChange={this.handleOptionChange}
          key={option.id.toString()}
          option={option}
        />
      );
    });
    let bShowOneSizeFitsMost = (variantSelectors.length === 1 && aOptionNames[0] === "Title");
    return (
      <div className="Product"> 
        {this.state.product.images.length ? <img src={variantImage.src} alt={`${this.state.product.title} product shot`}/> : null}
        <h5 className="Product__title">{this.state.product.title}</h5>
        <p>€{variant.price}</p>
        {bShowOneSizeFitsMost ? <h5 className="Product__title">{ONE_SIZE_FITS_MOST}</h5> : variantSelectors}
        <label className="Product__option">
          Quantity: <input className="form-control" min="1" type="number" defaultValue={variantQuantity} onChange={this.handleQuantityChange}></input>
        </label>
        <button className="Product__buy button" onClick={() => this.addVariantToCart(variant.id, variantQuantity)}>Add to Cart</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}




const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  checkout: selectCheckout
});

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
)(withRouter(ProductPage));
```

The code of the variantselector:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class VariantSelector extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <select
        className="Product__option"
        name={this.props.option.name}
        key={this.props.option.name}
        onChange={this.props.handleOptionChange}
      >
        {this.props.option.values.map((value) => {
          return (
            <option value={value} key={`${this.props.option.name}-${value}`}>{`${value}`}</option>
          )
        })}
      </select>
    );
  }
}

export default VariantSelector;
```

If I change the content (in the variant selector) of the option from
`<option value={value} key={`${this.props.option.name}-${value}`}>{`${value}`}</option>`
to
`<option value={value} key={`${this.props.option.name}-${value}`}>{`${value.value}`}</option>`,
it solves the issue (visually) in the option selector, but it still errors out when I try to select an other option. So I am thinking it has something to do with passing entire objects here. However, I can't find a way to make it work. Is the problem in the constructor function of the product page or in the combination of the VariantSelector and the handleOptionChange function?

If anyone has seen a similar problem, or knows what is causing it, I would love to hear. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `${this.props.option.name}-${value}` value is probably an object here, use some property inside it instead

Comment: You are right, this fixes the problem of the key and the content ont the front-end. But the TypeError: Cannot read property 'attrs' of undefined still persists as I try to select a different option. I am thinking this is because value={value} is still passing an object. But I'm not sure how to solve the problem.

Comment: `const selectedVariant = client.product.helpers.variantForOptions(this.state.product, selectedOptions)` is probably returning undefined

Comment: `value={value}` you can't pass an entire object on the option value, you could pass an index and then access it somehow, or any other unique prop that you can use to identify, you can console.log target.value on the handle change to debug this

Comment: Thank you, I will try to do so ^^. It is kinda weird though as that specific part is written by the shopify devs and it does work in an example piece of code like this

Comment: On a second look, something could also be making the values become objects once you refresh, hard to tell as I'm unable to debug, along the lines of `product.options.forEach((selector) => {
      defaultOptionValues[selector.name] = selector.values[0].value;
});`, would be helpful to have the console log of some lines around your constructor before and after refresh, or if you could make the repro more minimal https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, but it may be difficult due to the shopify API involved

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I got very sick for a few weeks, but almost better. A variant of the first solution you provided, combined with changing my handlechange function worked. I still don't know why this does not error in the example code and does in mine, but it works now. (I am thinking, maybe, something because I use redux-persist and it injects and refreshes the page as well). But it works! Thank you for thinking along with me, makes a real difference to have someone to talk with. Is there any way I can give you more likes or respects on here? With kind regards, Stijn

Comment: Do you have a link to the example code that works? And no, there's only upvotes, glad it helped fixing the error